# kubernetes python client was suspended when runing with watch.stream method

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes

I'm trying to watch the kubernetes resource like pods with kubernetes python client(version 9.0), but the method of watch.stream() seems to be suspended when i watch the k8s resource after few minutes later

```py
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
w = watch.Watch()
for resource in w.stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod):
    dosomething(resource)
```

how do i always keep watching the kebernetes pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting probably this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/728), and as workaround mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/728#issuecomment-455279700) you can try like below:

```
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError
config.load_kube_config()
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
while True:
  w = watch.Watch()
  try:
    for event in w.stream(api_instance.list_namespaced_pod, namespace="default"):
      print("Event: %s %s %s" % (event['type'],event['object'].kind, event['object'].metadata.name))
  except ProtocolError:
    print("watchPodEvents ProtocolError, continuing..")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx, but the `while True` loop doesn't work, maybe the firewall cut down the connection, i'm gonna redeploy the kubernetes client

Comment: Done, the firewall cut off the connection